# K & R section 1.10 example program skipping 'printf()' line

Tags: c

I'm learning C through K & R. I have reached to **section 1.10 External Variables and Scope.**
In that section they have written and explained program regarding external variable and their scope. I typed that code myself and tried to execute it. It does not show any run time or compile time error. However, it does not print any output also, which should be longest line from given input. I did debug the program and I found that program is **skipping 'printf()' statement**. I tried both on **sublime text 2 + gcc and Turbo c++ v4.5**, but still I don't get an output. I'm using Windows xpsp 3.
Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* program to pring longest line using external variables */

#define MAXSIZE 1000

int max;
char line[ MAXSIZE ];
char longest[ MAXSIZE ];

int getline( void );
void copy( void );

main()
{
    int len;

    extern int max;
    extern char longest[];

    max = 0;

    while( ( len = getline() ) > 0 )  
    {
        if( len > max )
        {
            len = max;
            copy();
        }
    }

    if( max > 0)
        printf("\n%s\n", longest);  /* This line is skipped */
    return 0;
}

int getline( void )  /* Check if there is line */
{
    int c, i;
    extern char line[];

    for( i = 0; i < MAXSIZE -1 && ( c = getchar()) != EOF &&  c != '\n'; ++i )
        line[ i ] = c;

     if( c == '\n' )
    {
        line[ i ] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    line[ i ] = '\0';

    return i;
}

void copy( void )  /* copy current line to longest if it is long */
{
    int i = 0;
    extern char line[];
    extern char longest[];

    while( ( longest[ i ] = line[ i ] ) != '\0' )
        ++i;
}
```

So my questions are :
**Why is this happening?

What should I do so that program won't skip 'printf()' and will print an output?**
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: `len = max;` should be `max = len;`

Comment: Note that `getline()` is now a POSIX function and this name should not be used for custom functions in new code.

Comment: Did you check what the value of max is?

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: `extern` in function scope? What, why?

Comment: these kinds of line: 'extern char line[];
    extern char longest[];' are not needed because the array definitions are in the same file.  'extern' is for data defined in other files.

Comment: @user3629249 I know that.. this is the first program i have written using 'extern' so for understanding purpose i kept that there

Answer (score 0):

The *intent* of this code is to start `max` at zero then, for every line longer than the current `max`, copy the line and update `max` to the longer value:

```
max = 0;
while( ( len = getline() ) > 0 )  
{
    if( len > max )
    {
        len = max;
        copy();
    }
}
```

However, the line that's supposed to update `max` is assigning in the wrong direction. It sets `len` to be the current value of `max` and *never updates* `max` at all. This is something that would have been obvious with a bit of "Debugging 101", placing the following line after the call to `copy()`:

```
printf ("New long line, len = %d, str = '%s'\n", max, longest);
```

That fact that you would never have seen the length changing would have (hopefully) narrowed down the problem pretty fast. The line in question should instead be:

```
max = len;
```